# Expand input suggestion width

Tags: sapui5

Screenshot of the current width:
[image]

I'm trying to expand the suggestion popup above.

Since I want to use it in a `FilterBar`, the Input fields are small and the Table becomes kind of useless. When trying to change the `width` with the Inspector, it changes back immediately.

The demo code I'm using is rather simple.

```xml
<Input xmlns="sap.m"
  showSuggestion="true"
  showTableSuggestionValueHelp="false"
  suggestionRows="{/ZSD_DebiaSet}"
  width="200px">
  <suggestionColumns>
    <Column popinDisplay="Inline" demandPopin="true">
      <Label text="Name"/>
    </Column>
    <Column hAlign="Center" popinDisplay="Inline" demandPopin="true" minScreenWidth="Tablet">
      <Label text="Product ID"/>
    </Column>
    <Column hAlign="Center" popinDisplay="Inline" minScreenWidth="Tablet">
      <Label text="Supplier Name"/>
    </Column>
    <Column hAlign="End" popinDisplay="Inline" demandPopin="true">
      <Label text="Price"/>
    </Column>
  </suggestionColumns>
  <suggestionRows>
    <ColumnListItem>
      <!-- ... -->
    </ColumnListItem>
  </suggestionRows>
</Input>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Controls extended from `sap.m.Input` (i.e. including `sap.m.MultiInput`) have a property called `maxSuggestionWidth` which will let you have a wider suggestion table than the actual width of your input. Check the property here: https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.m.Input#methods/setMaxSuggestionWidth

> If set, the value of this parameter will control the horizontal size of the suggestion list to display more data. This allows suggestion lists to be wider than the input field if there is enough space available. By default, the suggestion list is always as wide as the input field.
>
> **Note:** The value will be ignored if the actual width of the input field is larger than the specified parameter value.

I added this property with value `500px` (just for testing) and the result is the following (The `Input` width is `200px`):

[image]

I think this is what you are looking for ^^ Hope it helps!