# suggestion rows width increase in multi input field

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

- I have a MultiInput field in FilterBar when user enter the value suggestion table will display . [Sample 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfP8T.png)
- I have  5 column in suggestion table data is overlapping. The Suggestion table taking the width of that multiInput field. [sample 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcmVe.png)

How to increase the suggestion table width like that of sample 1?

```xml
        <fb:FilterBar <fb:FilterBar reset="onReset" class="sapUiSizeCompact" search="onSearch" useToolbar="false" showRestoreButton="false"
                            showClearButton="false">
                            <fb:filterGroupItems>
                                
                                
                                
                    <fb:FilterGroupItem groupName="Filters" partOfCurrentVariant="true" visibleInFilterBar="true" name="0F" label="Plant" labelTooltip="Plant"
                                    mandatory="false">
                                    <fb:control>
                                    
                        
                        <MultiInput showSuggestion="true" valueHelpRequest=".onValueHelpRequested" startSuggestion="2" suggestionRows="{/ProductCollection}">
                        
                            <suggestionColumns>
                                <Column>
                                    <Label text="ProductId"/>
                                </Column>
                                <Column>
                                    <Label text="Product Name"/>
                                </Column>
                                <Column>
                                    <Label text="Category"/>
                                </Column>
                                    <Column>
                                    <Label text="Description"/>
                                </Column>
                                <Column>
                                    <Label text="Main Category"/>
                                </Column>
                                
                                
                            </suggestionColumns>
                            <suggestionRows>
                                <ColumnListItem>
                                    <cells>
                                        <Label text="{ProductId}" />
                                        <Label text="{Name}" />
                                        <Label text="{Category}" />
                                        <Label text="{Description}" />
                                        <Label text="{MainCategory}" />
                                    </cells>
                                </ColumnListItem>
                            </suggestionRows>                   
                            
                        </MultiInput>                           
                                    </fb:control>
                                </fb:FilterGroupItem>                                               
                                
                                
                            </fb:filterGroupItems>
                        </fb:FilterBar>
```

Comment: [`maxSuggestionWidth`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.MultiInput%23controlProperties) If set, the value of this parameter will control the horizontal size of the suggestion list to display more data. This allows suggestion lists to be wider than the input field if there is enough space available. By default, the suggestion list is always as wide as the input field.

Comment: Thank you MrNajzs .. maxSuggestionWidth its working

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SAPUI5: Expand Input Table suggestionColumns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66763278/sapui5-expand-input-table-suggestioncolumns)